# What the difference between writing typescript configuration in package.json with vue-tsc or in tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vite, vue-tsc

I'm working on a project using typescript & vue3 & vite. It's a common component library, so when I build this project, I have to generate .d.ts declaration files.
I have tried in two ways:

1. Configing `emitDeclarationOnly: true` in tsconfig.json, but I got error `Option 'emitDeclarationOnly' cannot be specified with option 'noEmit'`. However, in my project, I didn't config `noEmit` option. So I think the `noEmit` option is from `node_modules`.
   This is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ],
    "paths":{
      "@": ["src"],
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
    },
    "types": ["node"],
  },
  "include": [      // 编译哪些文件
    // "src/**/.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx",
    ".eslintrc.cjs",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "vite.config.ts",
  ],
   "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

2. Configing `--emitDeclarationOnly` in package.json like below works fine for me:

```
"build": "vite build && vue-tsc --emitDeclarationOnly",
```

So I'm wondering what exactly the difference between configuration in `tsconfig.json` or in `package.json`?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add your `tsconfig.json` here?

Comment: I reedited the description and added `tsconfig.json`. Could you have a look again? Thank you.